# Regex: How to validate a password with the following parameters

Tags: regex, angular, typescript, validation

I've been trying to create a regex for Angular Validators pattern on a password field which has the following requirements:

- At least 2 uppercase letters
- At least 2 digits
- At least 1 special
  character.

At the moment I can get these working separatley for at least 1 of the characters required (1 uppercase, 1 digit and 1 special character):

```
(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>])
```

I can't seem to get the regex for at least 2 digits and uppercase letters in the password and then this all needs to be combined as well. Would anyone be able to help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just dup the tests in the lookaheads:

```
(?=(?:.*?[A-Z]){2})(?=(?:.*?[0-9]){2})(?=.*?[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>])
```

Comment: Perfect thank you so much! I find regular expressions difficult to wrap my head round sometimes!